# Getting a Stream<List<Object>> from a Stream<Event> from firebase real time database Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I'm very new to flutter Streams/Bloc/Provider and I'm following a tutorial to understand it.
In the tutorial dough they use Firestore so they get a Stream like this:

```
Stream<List<Todo>> todos() {
    return todoCollection.snapshots().map((snapshot) {
      return snapshot.documents 
          .map((doc) => Todo.fromEntity(TodoEntity.fromSnapshot(doc)))
          .toList();
    });
  }
```

Where their snapshot is `List<DocumentSnapshot>`, mine from `RTDB` is instead an `Event.`
I'm trying to get a `Stream<List<Object>>` from a `RTDB` node, but from the `.onValue()` property I get a `Stream<Event>`. 
Inside the `async` `map()` I access the `snapshot` Event but I don't get access to the `Dart.core`'s `map()`as in the example that uses `Firestore`, for it's not a List. 
`alerts()` is the Stream that the `bloc` will be listening to but it's expecting a `Stream<List<Object>>` and I can't get it.
How would I go to map it to a `Stream<List<Object>>` as I need?
Thank you very much for your time and help.
My code is:

```
// 
static UserAlert fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    return UserAlert(
        city: snapshot.value['City'],
        country: snapshot.value['Country'],
        date: snapshot.value['Date'],
        description: snapshot.value['Description'],
        id: snapshot.value['Id'],
        latitude: snapshot.value['Latitude'],
        longitude: snapshot.value['Longitude'],
        region: snapshot.value['Region'],
        timestamp: snapshot.value['Timestamp'],
        alertImageName: snapshot.value['alertImageName'],
        imageUrl: snapshot.value['imageUrl'],
        user: snapshot.value['user']);
  }


// try 1
Stream<List<UserAlert>> alerts() {
    return _databaseReference.onValue.map((snapshot) {
      // do the mapping to a Stream<List<UserAlert>>
    });
  }

 // try 2
 Stream<List<UserAlert>> alerts() {
return _databaseReference.onValue.toList(){ // Function expressions can't be named error

};
```

}

```
 // try 3
 Stream<List<UserAlert>> alerts() {
return _databaseReference.onValue.map(
    (snapshot) => UserAlert.fromSnapshot(snapshot); // wrong return type
);
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use StreamTransformer**

```
Stream<UserAlert> alerts() {
  handleData(Event event, EventSink<UserAlert> sink) =>
      sink.add(UserAlert.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot.value));

  final transformer =
      StreamTransformer<Event, UserAlert>.fromHandlers(handleData: handleData);

  return _databaseReference.onValue.transform(transformer);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is throwing an error dough
`The argument type 'Stream<Null>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<List<UserAlert>>'. Can you see what's happening?

Comment: How do you get the user alert list ? What is `_databaseReference.onValue`?

Comment: I don't yet. I've only able to get to the Stream<Event>  but I can't access any value from the stream.

Comment: How convert `Event` to `UserAlert`? `_databaseReference.onValue` will return `Stream<Event>`? Please show `_databaseReference` full code.

Comment: using the `fromSnapshot()` method but it accepts a `DataSnapshot` but I get back `Event`.. any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Event-class.html 
Here it states that one of the `Event` parameter is a `DataSnapshot` which I would use to create 'UserAlert' in `fromSnapshot()` method.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamTransformer-class.html

Comment: Yeah I also thought of StreamTransformer, but I'm to new to the concept to be able to use it.
I've been able to get to read the `Event.snapshot.value`and create an `UserAlert` out of it dough.

`dynamic listener = _databaseReference.onValue.listen((event) => UserAlert.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot.value));`

Comment: Great, we're getting there thank you. The only thing now is that is not returning `Stream<List<UserAlert>>`. So I tried changing `EventSink` to `EventSink<List<UserAlert>>` and transformer's `UserAlert` to `List<UserAlert>>` so now `sink.add` is expecting a `List<UserAlert>`. 
Any idea on how to make it into a List?

Comment: What is your use case ? Only one data to list is easy, but.... it's unnecessary.

Comment: Bloc is actually listen to it, but in the tutorial I'm following is listening to a `Stream<List<UserAlert>>`. Listening to a `Stream<UserAlert>`wouldn't mess it up?

Comment: I pass this `Stream<List<UserAlert>>` to add markers on a  `FlutterMap`

Comment: Im still learning it, I tried to add `.toList` in your code, but is throwing errors..
How would I change to stream a List? Dough unnecessary as you mentioned I rather try it that rethink the bloc.

Comment: Stream<List<UserAlert>> alerts() {
  handleData(Event event, EventSink<List<UserAlert>> sink) =>
      sink.add([UserAlert.fromSnapshot(event.snapshot)]);

  final transformer =
      StreamTransformer<Event, List<UserAlert>>.fromHandlers(handleData: handleData);

  return _databaseReference.onValue.transform(transformer);
}

Comment: Absolutely!! That's what I missed to change from your code, te squared brackets, Otherwise I did it right.
Many thanks for your help. I really appreciated it.
Cheers

Comment: alerts().listen((alert) {
  final aList = [alert];
});

Comment: Is this to listen to the `Stream<UserAlert>` in the bloc right?
I'l give a try to both way then. Thank you again very much!

Comment: Good luck~~ Cheers